# Moving from TableView to 2nd TableView & back to tab(TabBar)

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, tableview, viewcontroller

I've a ViewController with TableView in my StoryBoard (SecondViewController) and when I click on a row I want to move to 2nd ViewController with TableView (ListPlacesViewController) in my StoryBoard and then when I click on a row in the 2nd TableView I want to return to a specific tab (TabBar).

Any ideas how I do that?

Comment: so far i'm looking at the net and found this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457
but i'm not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: Well, first of all; I dont understand the question clearly. If you want to go to corresponding tag based upon the selection of certain tableview cell you should do self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1 based upon your need and then when certain tableview is clicked do the similar think.

Comment: i have a viewcontroller in my storyboard which is not connected to anything (listplacesviewcontroller) and a viewcontroller (secondviewcontroller) which is connected to the storyboard by tabbar. in android i have setContentView, is there anything similar? so if i click on a cell/row in my secondviewcontroller i will bring to the front the listplacesviewcontroller. like the link i gave earlier (the apple developer example).